# Reference cell-specific JSON key in DetailView w/o using didSelectRowAtIndexPath in Swift

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift, segue

My `UITableView` cells are setup with a `UIButton` that segues to my DetailVC. **I don't want to segue based on a full cell selection**, but instead exclusively through the button. My issue is that I need to pass a `JSON` key that's specific to my cell through this segue. In this case, each cell has a specific **"id"** that I need to pass as a variable to the DetailVC for later us in an http request.

Is there a way to segue and pass the key through an `@IBAction`?

Below is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. I need to pass **"needID"**, or the key **"id"** to my DetailView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CustomCell

    var rowData: NSDictionary = dataArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    var needID=rowData["id"] as String
    var firstName=rowData["needFirstname"] as String
    var descrip=rowData["needDescription"] as String
    var poster=rowData["needPoster"] as String
    var city=rowData["needCity"] as String
    var state=rowData["needState"] as String
    var country=rowData["needCountry"] as String

    cell.needID.text = needID
    cell.needFirstName.text = firstName
    cell.needDescription.text = descrip; cell.needDescription.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.needPoster.text = poster
    cell.needCity.text = city
    cell.needState.text = state
    cell.needCountry.text = country

    return cell
}
```

In my DetailVC, I've prepped for the id to fill the following variable:

```
var passedID:String = ""
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  (All code was written without compiling, so you might need to tweak a tad).
Store the row number as the button's tag.  Then you'll be able to use that to retrieve the id.

1) Add an `@IBOutlet` to your button in your CustomCell.

```
@IBOutlet myButton:UIButton!
```

2) In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

3) In `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "myCellButtonSegue" {
        if let mybutton = sender as? UIButton {
            let rowData: NSDictionary = dataArray[mybutton.tag] as NSDictionary
            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            dvc.passedID = rowData["id"] as String
        }
    }
}
```

If your destination view controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, I believe you should do this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "myCellButtonSegue" {
        if let mybutton = sender as? UIButton {
            let rowData: NSDictionary = dataArray[mybutton.tag] as NSDictionary
            let navcon = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
            let dvc = navcon.topViewController as DetailViewController
            dvc.passedID = rowData["id"] as String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this making much more sense, but it throws an error on the cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row line, saying it found undexpected nil while unwrapping the optional

Comment: Did you wire the button to the @IBOutlet by dragging from the button to the outlet?

Comment: yep just noticed that myself, now it's launching, but upon button click it crashes now on the line dvc.passedID = rowData["id"] as String in the prepareForSegue func

Comment: btw, thank you very much for your patience with this, it is greatly appreciated

Comment: Getting closer.  Does the button.tag have a good value.  Is the dvc pointer nil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60344/discussion-between-dvdowns-and-vacawama).